# Design diagram for html pages

Tags: uml, software-design

My project is developing a website only with simple html pages. To start the project i have to  first do the design documents iam not able to understand what kind of UML diagram should i use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't need to have UML documentation, but, when used properly, I can be very helpful.

Three types of diagrams that help me a lot are:

[1] (Object and) Class Diagram

Start with this. In case of simple HTML pages, its very easy. Just draw each specific page your website is going to have, with a class.

In this, example, we have a website store with a "Main" page (index.html),
and a "Products" page. In the case of static HTML pages,
you can skip "properties", "methods".

```
..............................................
..+----------------+..+--------------------+..
..| * : MainPage   |..| * : ProductsPage   |..
..+----------------+..+--------------------+..
..|                |..|                    |..
..|                |..|                    |..
..|                |..|                    |..
..+----------------+..+--------------------+..
..............................................
```

[2] Activity Diagram ("U.M.L. Flowchar")

When your user clicks on a link from a page, which is going the next page ?

```
......................
.........(O)..........
..........|...........
..........|...........
..........v...........
..+----------------+..
..|  Enter         |..
..|  (MainPage);   |..
..|                |..
..+----------------+..
..........|...........
..........|...........
..........v...........
..+----------------+..
..|  ClickLink     |..
..| (CatalogPage); |..
..|                |..
..+----------------+..
..........|...........
..........|...........
..........v...........
..+----------------+..
..|  Enter         |..
..| (CatalogPage); |..
..|                |..
..+----------------+..
..........|...........
..........|...........
..........v...........
.........(X)..........
......................
```

[3] Sequence diagrams

They are similar to Activity Diagrams, but, are more complex,
they are more like a two dimensional diagrams.

Use them, only if you understand them well.

```
.........................................................................
......+--------------+.....+--------------+........+-----------------+...
......| * : User     |.....+ * : MainPage +........| * : CatalogPage |...
......+-------+------+.....+------+-------+........+--------+--------+...
..............|...................|.........................|............
............+-+-+...............+-+-+.....................+-+-+..........
....start().|   |...enter().....|   |.....................|   |..........
.(O)=======>+   +==============>+   |.....................|   |..........
............|   |...............|   |..Show().............|   |..........
............|   |...............|   +===+.................|   |..........
............|   |...............|   |...!.................|   |..........
........+---+   |<--------------|   +<==+.................|   |..........
........|...|   |...............|   |.....................|   |..........
........|...|   |.ClickLink.....|   |.....................|   |..........
........|...|   |...("Catalog").|   |.......enter().......|   |..Show()..
........+-->+   +==============>+   +====================>+   +===+......
............|   |...............|   |.....................|   |...!......
............|   |...............+-+-+.....................|   |...!......
...finish().|   |.........................................|   |...!......
.( )<-------+   +<----------------------------------------+   +<==+......
............|   |.........................................|   |..........
............+-+-+.........................................+---+..........
.........................................................................
```

Note: In this example, the user ("actor") its displayed as block class.

Remember, don't corce yourself to use a U.M.L. diagram, if you don't understand them,
it will make your work difficult, instead of helping you.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi, you too could use [WebML](http://www.webml.org) as a good complement to UML for navigation specification.

Answer (score 0):

In most scenarios, use cases will help you to identify at least the functional requirements. Activity diagrams can be good for plotting the user interaction with a website. Thereafter you might use sequence or component diagrams. Class diagrams typically appear late.

But basically, the choice is entirely up to you. UML does not set or require any process constraints. The diagrams just offer different views on the same subject. Just get hold of a UML book and get a first impression which diagram type is best for what; it seems from your question that basic knowledge is missing there (as you did not point out any research that you did already).

Keep in mind UML is not your only choice. Maybe a mindmap will do. That depends on your task.

Comment: my main doubt is that can i use a class diagram when there are no classes in my project

Comment: OK if you don't need classes, you'll not want to waste time on this diagram type. You generally draw diagrams in an economic way, i.e. only include in your model what you really think you need.